# Angular passing variables between child and parent HTML

Tags: html, angular

I'm having some issues to pass a variable from one HTML to its child HTML. Code explanation below:

in app.component.html I'm using ngFor and declaring the variables taskElement and i:

`<app-task *ngFor="let taskElement of taskElements; let i=index" [taskElement]="taskElement"></app-task>`

And in the app-task child HTML I have a button where I need to use the i variable:

```
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <span>
                {{element.description}}
            </span>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" style="float: right;" type="button" (click)="deleteTask(i)">Remove
                Task</button>
        </li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

I've also tried to redeclare the ngFor inside app-task, but this was causing the list to be duplicated. Is there a way to use the "i" variable inside the child app-task?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can add a second `Input` into your component that accepts an integer. So you can bind the variable `i` to it.

Comment: This Input would be inside app.component? But how would I link it with the other html file?

Comment: The component `app-task` currently accepts a `taskElement` so I suggest adding another input property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest is using an `Output()` in the child component for when the button is clicked.  That way, you can handle the logic requiring the index variable `i` in the parent component where it is declared, and the child component can stay dumb and happy:

```js
export class TaskComponent {
    @Output()
    deleteClick = new EventEmitter<void>();

    deleteButtonClicked() {
        this.deleteClick.next();
    }
}
```

Parent component HTML:

```html
<app-task 
    *ngFor="let taskElement of taskElements; let i=index"
    [taskElement]="taskElement"
    (deleteClick)="deleteTask(i)"
></app-task>
```

### Another approach

Instead of forcing the child component to be dumb and the parent component to be smart, another approach, which I think is better personally, is to have both components be dumb and have them both depend on a service class that keeps track of all of your tasks.  Since your child component has an `Input` for the task element, when the user clicks the delete button in the child component, you could just call the `deleteTask` method in this hypothetical service class, and have the collection of tasks be refreshed automatically for the parent component's `ngFor` loop.

Comment: Thanks Jake! That did the trick :)